# How to use a string variable with the system() function in C++

Tags: c++

Recently I have developed a program in which I have to call `system();` which takes in a `const char*`. I need to utilize an array of strings in this call. Here is some sample code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string stackoverflow[5] = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};
    int i = 0;

    while(i <= 5)
    {
        system("wget -O" + stackoverflow[i] + "\"www.google.com\"");
        i++;
    }   
}
```

Side note: I tried using `const char b = stackoverflow[i].c_str()` but I got errors:

> expression must have integral or unscoped enum type

and

> '+' cannot add two pointers

BTW, I am using Visual Studio. I have no clue what I should do at this point.

Thanks for reading. I'm pretty newbie so any help would be appreciated. I would appreciate a solution not needing to translate my array to vectors because I have alot of code in this project and that will require restructuring a shit ton of code. PS sorry for the indentation i was able to fail at c+p

Comment: `const char b = stackoverflow[i].c_str()` you are assigning a pointer to char to a char instead of a pointer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a combined string first and then use the `std::string.c_str()` function.

```
std::string combined = "wget -O" + stackoverflow[i] + "\"www.google.com\"";
system(combined.c_str());
```

Comment: Solved! (Waiting for timer to officially accept.)

Comment: Don't forget to fix the `while(i <= 5)` bug, too (should be `<` instead of `<=`, otherwise you go out of bounds of the array).

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
int main()
{
    string stackoverflow[5] = {"1","2","3","4","5"};
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 5)
    {
        string args = "wget -O" + stackoverflow[i] + "\"www.google.com\"";
        system(args.c_str());
        i++;
    }
}
```